# Tasks Stuck in Celery Queue

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, rabbitmq, celery

I had been trying to implement a task queue with Redis Queue that sat on top of Redis. I got rid of this and went to Celery on top of RabbitMQ based on problems I was having as described here: [Redis Queue blocking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59927864/redis-queue-blocking)

I reference the above ( unanswered) SO question as I believe the two issues are similiar enough to be potentially linked - be that code or setup on my part.

I am able to send tasks to my Celery Queue, and am able to see them sat there either by calling `rabbitmqctl list_queues` within my Rabbit docker container bash, or by calling

`>>> add_nums.delay(2,3)`

`<AsyncResult: 197315b1-e18b-4945-bf0a-cc6b6b829bfb>`

`>>> result = add_nums.AsyncResult( 197315b1-e18b-4945-bf0a-cc6b6b829bfb)`

where

`>>> result.status`
`'PENDING'`

regardless of how many times I check.

I have tried adding `ignore_result=True` within the decorator call but this has no effect.

my worker class:

```
./workerA.py
from celery import Celery
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger

logger = get_task_logger( __name__)

# Celery configuration
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://***:***@rabbit:5672/' #where the asterisks indicate user, pwd
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'rpc://'

# Initialize celery
celery = Celery( 'workerA', 
        broker=CELERY_BROKER_URL,
        backend=CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND)

@celery.task( ignore_result=True)
def add_nums( a, b):
    logger.info( f'{ a+b=}')
    return a+b
```

My main:

```
./app.py
import logging
from flask.logging import default_handler
from workerA import add_nums
from workerB import sub_nums
from flask import (
        Flask,
        request,
        jsonify,
    )

logger = logging.getLogger( )
logger.addHandler( default_handler)
logger.setLevel( logging.INFO)

app = Flask( __name__)

@app.route( '/')
def index():
    return 'hello world!'

@app.route( '/add')
def add():
    logger.info( 'in add method')
    first_num, second_num = ( 1,2)

    logger.info( f' { first_num=}')

    result = add_nums.delay( first_num, second_num)
    logger.info( f' {result=}')
    logger.info( f' {result.state=}')

    return jsonify({ 'result': result.result}), 200

@app.route( '/subtract')
def subtract():
    logger.info( 'in sub method')
    first_num, second_num = ( 1,2)

    result = sub_nums.delay( first_num, second_num)
    logger.info( f' {result=}')

    return jsonify( {'result': result.result}), 200

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run( debug=True)
```

Calling `result.get( timeout=n)` always results in a timeout, regardless of how high n is set: in short these queues are never fulfilled.

For completeness, my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    command: python ./app.py -h 0.0.0.0
    depends_on:
      - rabbit
    volumes:
      - .:/app
  rabbit:
    hostname: rabbit
    image: rabbitmq:management
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=***
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=***
    ports:
      - "5673:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
  worker_1:
    build:
      context: .
    hostname: worker_1
    entrypoint: celery
    command: -A workerA worker --loglevel=info -Q workerA
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    links:
      - rabbit
    depends_on:
      - rabbit
  worker_2:
    build:
      context: .
    hostname: worker_2
    entrypoint: celery
    command: -A workerB worker --loglevel=info -Q workerB
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    links:
      - rabbit
    depends_on:
      - rabbit
```

and my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3

ADD requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app/

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 5000
```

I am using Docker Desktop for Mac 2.2.0.0 and my OSX is 10.15.2 ( Catalina)

any and every help on this issue would be greatly appreciated. These queue problems have now become a serious blocker for me

Comment: Your worker is subscribed to the `workerA`, yet you are sending the task to the default (`celery`) queue with `add_nums.delay(2,3)`... Try `add_nums.appy_async((2,3), queue="workerA")`

Comment: I thought it worked, but now I'm not sure it did. Should I need a Pika client to extract the result? I was under the impression that I could get the result from Celery by doing something of the form result.get() where result is defined as either a task.delay() or task.apply_assync()

Comment: `result.get()` would block forever if I am right... But if you send the task to the active queue, then it should return fairly quickly with expected result.

Comment: I have changed the definition of the Celery object ( celery) in workerA.py such that it is now defined as
```celery = Celery( 'celery', broker=CELERY_BROKER_URL, backend=CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND)```
This should mean that in calling the method, ```add_nums.apply_async( (2,3), queue='celery')``` ought to have the same effect as ```add_nums.delay(2,3)``` using the above premise. In both case, calling `.get()` on this has no effect, and status remains `PENDING` forever

Comment: Yes, that is what I would expect, since your worker is subsribed to the`workerA` queue (`... -Q workerA ...`), and you are explicitly sending to the `celery` queue... I am out of this conversation...

Answer (score 2):

It would appear that the cause of this problem is because there is no configured backend to store the results. Instantiating Celery object with Celery(..., backend='rpc://') seemingly does nothing other than silence the "NotImplementedError: No result backend is configured" error you would otherwise get. I believe the documentation in this sense to be misleading.

Off to trial a Redis result backend for performance. I also have Elasticsearch and MongoDB in use elsewhere for my application which I could target, but fancy Redis more. Will feed back results when this is done, after lunch.

Comment: Yes, switching out backend='rpc://' for my redis instance - which in this case happens to be redis://redis:6379 works fine. 
So _either_ the suggested "rpc://" doesn't work in general, _or_ it doesn't work in Docker